# I can't download a ZIP file from the Sitefinity CMS Export / Import menu

Tags: c#, sitefinity, sitefinity-10, sitefinity-13

I want to download a ZIP file from Sitefinity CMS Export / Import menu, but after I clicked "Export to ZIP file" button I've got this error: Data have not been successfully exported. I've tried to export each item individually, but the result was still the same.

Steps to reproduce:
Go to Sitefinity CMS (Admin site) -> Administration -> Export / Import -> Download ZIP file -> select just 1 item -> click "Export to Zip file" button -> the error appears on the Browser: Data have not been
successfully exported.

Detail error message,
On the CMS: Data have not been successfully exported

On the Chrome DevTools:
`Response Code 500. ErrorCode: InvalidOperationException. Message: Scheduling is not enabled`

The Error.log from App_Data/sitefinity/Logs:

```
----------------------------------------
ActivityId: 55XXX // obscured info

Timestamp: 11/11/2020 4:44:49 AM

Message: HandlingInstanceID: d9XXX // obscured info
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred and was caught.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
11/11/2020 04:44:49
Type : System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX // obscured info
Message : Scheduling is not enabled
Source : Telerik.Sitefinity.Packaging
Help link : 
Data : System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal
TargetSite : Void ScheduleTask(Telerik.Sitefinity.Scheduling.ScheduledTask)
HResult : -2146233079
Stack Trace :    at Telerik.Sitefinity.Packaging.Web.Services.PackagingWebService.ScheduleTask(ScheduledTask task)
   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceExec`1.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<CreateExecFn>b__0(Object service, Object request) in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\ServiceExec.cs:line 132
   at ServiceStack.Host.ServiceRunner`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__15.MoveNext() in C:\BuildAgent\work\3481147c480f4a2f\src\ServiceStack\Host\ServiceRunner.cs:line 133

Additional Info:

MachineName : XXX // obscured info
TimeStamp : 11/11/2020 4:44:49 AM
FullName : Telerik.Sitefinity.Utilities, Version=13.0.7326.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX // obscured info
AppDomainName : /LM/W3SVC/XXX // obscured info
ThreadIdentity : a@b.com // obscured info
WindowsIdentity : IIS APPPOOL\XXX // obscured info
Requested URL : [h-t-t-p-s://]www.XXX.com/RestApi/Sitefinity/packaging/archive // obscured info


Category: ErrorLog

Priority: 0

EventId: 90000

Severity: Error

Title:Enterprise Library Exception Handling

Machine: XXX // obscured info

App Domain: XXX // obscured info

ProcessId: XXX // obscured info

Process Name: D:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\w3wp.exe

Thread Name: 

Win32 ThreadId:XXX // obscured info

Extended Properties: 
----------------------------------------
```

Please give me a clue, how to solve this error? I've done research a bit and I get this link: [h-t-t-p-s://][www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-scheduled-tasks](http://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/for-developers-scheduled-tasks)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **Administration > Modules and Services** and make sure the Scheduling service is activated.

Comment: thank you! your answer is only about 2 hours late compared to Sitefinity support's answer

Comment: because we are in different timezones :)